# FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage - fragment not preserved on redirect

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, uri-fragment

I have a page, URI looks like this:
http://domain.example.com/Profiles/Profile.aspx?username=blah#blahtab

When that fragment (#blahtab) is present, some jQuery picks up on that and displays a different section of the page initially.

However, that page requires a user to authenticate first. Coming back from the authentication step using FormsAuthentication, the fragment is discarded, regardless of the UrlEncode step.

I don't see the fragment actually sent to the server when I use a debugger on my local machine. Is this standard fare and the fragment is only for the client side?

How can I keep that tacked on without writing my own redirection code on the login page?

Alternately, should I use another method to preserve the view of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was unaware of this: [the URL fragment is never sent to the server.](http://www.bryancook.net/2008/04/aspnet-uri-fragment-is-not-available.html)

I will have to find an alternative implementation.